# Not able to build APK, duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/TextUtilsCompat.class

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, native

My application can be deployed successfully into my mobile device, but when I try exporting an APK, that can't build properly.

I tried a lot of thing, but can't fix that issue.

If someone have an idea, would be a pleasure :).

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.softcaze.clopin"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.0')
compile project(path: ':HoloGraphLibrary')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
}
```

And the error I get is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/TextUtilsCompat.class

And the gradle file for : compile project(path: ':HoloGraphLibrary') is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
}
```

I can't find a duplicate dependency.

Comment: i think ur using some lib file into `HoloGraphLibrary` so if u include some lib into ur `HoloGraphLibrary` then u dnt need to include into ur project ....

Comment: HoloGraphLibrary source are here : https://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary. They don't seems to use external library, maybe I am wrong.